# "Autofill" a texbox with a date one year ahead of the inputted date from the first texbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

i'm new to php and just got little trouble here. Basically i'm creating a system that adds vehicle registration details into the database. 
Before, the ADD Form has to be inputted with all the details including the RECEIPT DATE and the EXPIRY of the REGISTRATION which is obviously one year after the RECEIPT DATE.
I provided date pickers for each textbox and worked. but now I realized, it would be better if i just have to input the RECEIPT DATE, and the EXPIRY OF REGISTRATION would automatically be filled with the date one year after the RECEIPT DATE, for my system to be more "smart".

Provided below is my HTML code for the two inputs, the RECEIPT DATE and the PERMIT EXPIRY (which is the expiry of registration).

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks. Sorry for my poor programming skills.

```html
<div class="control-group"> 
     <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword" >Official Receipt Date:</label><br>
<div class="controls">
                    
<input name="receiptdate" type="text" class="w8em format-y-m-d highlight-days-67 range-low" id="sd1" style="border: 3px double #CCCCCC;" maxlength="10" readonly="readonly" required/>
                    
</div>
</div>


<div class="control-group"> 
<label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Permit Expiry:</label><br>
<div class="controls">           
<input name="receiptdate" type="text" id="date" style="border: 3px double #CCCCCC;" maxlength="10" readonly="readonly" required/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have tried numerous javascripts, but none seems to work. before the javascripts i tried the process on the sql,thinking that is would be easier to do it but my adviser said it isnt possible because the whole action is happening on the "front" of the system.

Comment: I could help you. But first question, Which datepicker are you using? Bootstrap || jquery-ui ?